# Script to download file by name according to date on a Windows?

Tags: windows, vbscript

I need to daily run a script that will download a file from a fixed location (http://www.meteoman.it/ilmeteo/audio/) and save it on my computer.
The format of filename is yyyy-mm-dd.mp3 and everyday a new file in added.
The script must recognize the date and save the appropriate file whit the date of today in the folder "today" and the file whit the date of tomorrow in the folder "tomorrow".
thank you !!!

the script if for automate the forecast on my web-radio
the file of forecast are freeware
sorry for my English!
cheers from Italy

Comment: So... what's your question? This is a programming help site, not a place to ask people to write programs for you.

Comment: 1) the problem is that neither VBScript nor JScript have built-in functions that would format the date in the format I need.

Comment: sorry .. continue here! 2)I don't know how i can use the date for the filename. Sorry I am not a programmer. TNX anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The calls to `Right` are to pad the month and day with a leading zero if needed (adds a zero to any month/day and then extract only the last 2 digits).

```
dt = Date
yearStr = Year(dt)
monthStr = Right("0" & Month(dt), 2)
dayStr = Right("0" & Day(dt), 2)
fileName = yearStr & "-" & monthStr & "-" & dayStr & ".mp3"
```

To get tomorrow's date, just change the first line to:

```
dt = DateAdd("d", 1, Date)
```

Answer (score 0):

here the script ! tnx all!

```
    dt = Date
yearStr = Year(dt)
monthStr = Right("0" & Month(dt), 2)
dayStr = Right("0" & Day(dt), 2)
fileName = yearStr & "-" & monthStr & "-" & dayStr & ".mp3"



 ' Set your settings
    strFileURL = "http://www.meteoman.it/ilmeteo/audio/" & filename
    strHDLocation = "c:\today\today.mp3"
' Fetch the file
    Set Ws = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Set objXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    objXMLHTTP.open "GET", strFileURL, false
    objXMLHTTP.send()
If objXMLHTTP.Status = 200 Then
Set objADOStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
objADOStream.Open
objADOStream.Type = 1 'adTypeBinary
objADOStream.Write objXMLHTTP.ResponseBody
objADOStream.Position = 0    'Set the stream position to the start
Set objFSO = Createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If objFSO.Fileexists(strHDLocation) Then objFSO.DeleteFile strHDLocation
Set objFSO = Nothing
objADOStream.SaveToFile strHDLocation
objADOStream.Close
Set objADOStream = Nothing
End If
' Set objXMLHTTP = Nothing 
' Ws.Run strHDLocation
' Set WS = Nothing
```